# Error with Scheduled Batch Classes

Tags: apex, unit-test, schedulebatch

I have 2 batch Apex classes that update Account fields from different custom objects. I was running into issues of accessing records and found a way to run the batches in order. The test class for my 1st batch runs and covers my classes.  When I run the 2nd test class, I get the following error & Stack Trace:

> System.StringException: Only CronTrigger IDs and batch, future, and
> queueable job IDs are supported.
>
> Class.AccountTotalReferralsBatch.finish: line 23, column 1

Can anyone help me resolve this error?

**Batch Class:**

```
public class AccountTotalReferralsBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id FROM Account]);
    }
    public void execute(Database.batchableContext context, Account[] scope) {
        Map<Id, AggregateResult> results = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>([
            SELECT Account__c Id, COUNT(Id) amt 
            FROM Referral__c 
            WHERE Account__c = :scope AND Age__c<366 GROUP BY Account__c]);
            
        for(Account record: scope) {
            AggregateResult amount = results.get(record.Id);
            if(amount != null) {
                record.Referrals__c = (Decimal)amount.get('amt');
            } else {
                record.Referrals__c = null;
            }
        }
        update scope;
    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        BatchSchedule__c b = BatchSchedule__c.getOrgDefaults();
            System.abortJob(b.Scheduled_Id__c);
    }         
}
```

**Scheduler Class:**

```
global class AccountTotalReferralsSchedule implements Schedulable{
    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc){
        AccountTotalReferralsBatch ref = new AccountTotalReferralsBatch();
        database.executebatch(ref,200);
    }
}
```

**Test Class:**

```
@istest (SeeAllData=FALSE)
public class AccountTotalReferralsTest{
    
    public static testmethod void testBatch1() {
        Test.startTest();
        
        Account account = TestUtility.createAccount('Prospect', Constants.RECORDTYPEID_ACCOUNT_FAMILY);
        insert account;
        
        Contact contact = TestUtility.createContact(account.Id, Constants.RECORDTYPEID_CONTACT_FAMILY, 'Primary');
        insert contact;
        
        Encounters__c encounter = TestUtility.createEncounter(account.Id, contact.Id, '', '');
        insert encounter;
        
        BatchSchedule__c batchSchedEnc = new BatchSchedule__c();
        insert batchSchedEnc;
        
AccountTotalReferralsBatch();

            string chron = '0 0 23 * * ?';
            string jobid = System.schedule('testScheduledApex', chron, new AccountTotalEncountersSchedule());
            CronTrigger ct = [Select id , CronExpression from CronTrigger where id = :jobId];

        Referral__c testRef = new Referral__c();
        testRef.Name = 'Test';
        testRef.Account__c = account.Id;
        insert testRef;

        batchSchedEnc = [SELECT Id,Scheduled_Id__c FROM BatchSchedule__c WHERE ID =: batchSchedEnc.Id];
            batchSchedEnc.Scheduled_Id__c = ct.Id;
        
        AccountTotalReferralsBatch testBatch = new AccountTotalReferralsBatch();
        
        Database.executebatch(testBatch);        
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a typo where you are scheduling the class? In your test class I see `AccountTotalEncountersSchedule` whereas in the question you have it as `AccountTotalReferralsSchedule`.

Comment: Does that custom setting field have a value? If so, what is it?

Comment: @JayantDas I have the AccountTotalEncountersSchedule class in there to create a batch record that the custom setting would access for the AccountTotalReferralsAchedule class

Comment: @AdrianLarson The Custom Setting has 1 field (Scheduled_Id__c) that has a default value of 0 and is a text field. I am using that to abort the 1st scheduled class so the 2 classes can run in sequence.

Comment: you should unit test the first batchable and verify it starts the second batchable; then unit test the second batchable. Trying to test across async transactions within 1 testmethod leads to many issues

Comment: @J.Neilan I could be reading this wrong, but did you just forget to add `update batchSchedEnc;` after the line `batchSchedEnc.Scheduled_Id__c = ct.Id;`?

Comment: @Bow-chicawow-ers Wow, I completely missed that. That did the trick. Can you add as an answer so I can mark it.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Sure thing. As the lone developer at my company, love the virtual code review community we've got here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're just missing `update batchSchedEnc;` after the line `batchSchedEnc.Scheduled_Id__c = ct.Id;`